# How to create and associate another model during creation in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a one-to-many relationship and I'd like to create and associate the related model to the model being created at creation time.

Here I have `User` and `Item` models. When a user is first created, the user should get a default item automatically:

```
class User(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, default="", unique=True)
    items = relationship('Item', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.items.append(...)    # <---- Add default item here?

class Item(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, default="")
    userid = Column(Integer,  ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

But I'm not sure how to append the new Item in `User.__init__()`? Is it something like:

```
# in User __init__()
item = Item(name="default item")
self.items.append(item)
session.add(item)
```

But then I"m unclear what happens to the transaction if something fails on either model, and whether I need to call `session.add(item)` or if appending the item to user automatically does this.

ie, what happens to the transaction when I create a user and this throws an error because `name` is not unique. Will the item still be created?

```
def doit():
    myuser = User(name='bob')   # <---- Say "bob" is already in DB
    session.add(myuser)
    session.commit()
```

What is the valid way of creating a default Item for User at user creation time?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. You need to commit the parent model first. When you think about how this is working in the background, it actually makes sense. You can't assign a model to have a foreign key when that foreign key isn't yet determined.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve these types of problems is to create some test code. I find prototyping in a sqlite memory database works very well.

So if the relationship is configured correctly - like in your case - sqlalchemy will figure out the key relation and automatically set the foreign key.

But seeing is believing, I have added some sample code that has unittests for the scenarios you describe.
Before each test I drop and recreate all tables to ensure the schema is clean.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()


from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, default="", unique=True)
    items = relationship('Item', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.items.append(Item(name='DefaultItem'))


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, default="", unique=True)  # Unique so we can create a failing test
    user_id = Column(Integer,  ForeignKey('user.id'))


from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from contextlib import contextmanager


engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()


import unittest


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)  # Reset

    def tearDown(self):
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)  # Reset

    def test_sanity(self):
        with session_scope() as session:
            self.assertEqual(session.query(User).all(), [])
            self.assertEqual(session.query(Item).all(), [])

    def test_item_automatically_added(self):
        with session_scope() as session:
            user = User(name='John')
            session.add(user)

        with session_scope() as session:
            user = session.query(User).filter(User.name == 'John').one()
            self.assertIsNotNone(user.items.filter(Item.name == 'DefaultItem').one())

    def test_duplicate_item_causes_user_save_to_fail(self):
        with session_scope() as session:
            item = Item(name='DefaultItem')
            session.add(item)

        from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            with session_scope() as session:
                user = User(name='John')
                session.add(user)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

So these tests cover all the scenarios except for one. If the user fails to be created the test will fail. I couldn't think of an easy way to do this test but I did check the sql echo output

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES (?)
2015-09-15 20:55:49,834 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES (?)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:('John',)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INSERT INTO item (name, user_id) VALUES (?, ?)
2015-09-15 20:55:49,834 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('John',)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:('DefaultItem', 1)
2015-09-15 20:55:49,834 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO item (name, user_id) VALUES (?, ?)
```

User is always inserted before item so we cannot get dangling items anyway. To be even more sure of this you could make the item.user_id foreign key not nullable.

Comment: What will be the query if I want all users who don't have any items associated with them.